# Cannot select a value from a (related) picklist

Tags: case, picklist, profile, page-layout, dependent-picklist

I have created a dependent picklist on the Case object. However, on the layout, I am not able to select any of the picklist values (see attached image). Both fields have read/write permissions for the profile that I'm using to test, so what could be the problem?[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check if you are using any Record Types for Case. If yes the picklist values must be added for the Record Type you are using.

Go to Case Record Types --> Open the Record Type you are using --> Click on Edit on the Picklist field you are using --> Add the picklist values as required.

Do the steps for both the controlling and the dependent picklist field